# Bootstrap rows and text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a form which is horizontal and want to put a full word in between the two columns as below. If I use another  tag it creates too much padding on either side of this word, and if I just put in a label or a plain text character surrounded by no tags, it ruins the position of the domain box. How can I make this work without overwriting the styles in the bootstrap.css?

I would like the form to be completely horizontal.

```
<div class="row">
        <label for="www" class="col-sm-1 control-label">
            Label1 
        </label>


    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" /> 
    </div>

    <!-- Word to go here-->

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">go</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear how you want this to be rendered.

Comment: Apologises, this has been updated. Due to BS3 12 column structure I would like this to sit within a container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to follow bootstrap's 12 col grid system and specify one column `col-sm-1` for the word, so that all columns add up to 12.

http://jsfiddle.net/bRh2z/show

http://jsfiddle.net/bRh2z/

```
    <div class="row">
    <label for="www" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Label1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">woooord</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">go</button>
    </div>
</div>
```